# What is the ideal way to store player statistics in a simple game

Tags: ios

I’m looking to build a simple game as a personal project, and I was wondering what the preferred way to store player statistics is. In my professional line of work, I’ve worked with SQL databases, CoreData and so on. However, this simple game would really only need to store integers of the player’s stats. I’m wondering if NSUserDefaults is fine to use for this (simplest way, that way the game can act as an example even for beginners which is part of my purpose). I’m wondering however if using NSUserDefaults this way is looked down upon or not an ideal usage for it, and if there’s any drawback to it that I may not be aware of. The bonus to it is NSUserDefaults gives you iCloud backup for free, for the user. If anyone had any other suggestions, they are welcomed as well.

Comment: Would you want your players to come back after they've deleted the game with the same statistics? If yes, then you probably want to use a service like Firebase or some other BaaS service

Comment: If you are only storing a few statistics, like the current level, high score, etc. - definitely just store the data in NSUserDefaults. I think CoreData would be overkill for this. If you are going to use the app for teaching, using local storage like an SQL database or CoreData would add a huge learning curve that might take away from the true purpose (learning to code a game).

Comment: @MSU_Bulldog I think the same. Quite frankly, I’m thinking that the best way to do this might be to build methods which update a specific key in both NSUserDefaults (for local storage) and NAUbiquitousKeyValueStore (for iCloud storage), since data has to be able to be recovered upon reinstall in case the user deletes (since NSUserDefault only preserves itself from backup, not reinstall). It might not be the most efficient to have a method updating these two keys for every single stat that must be tracked, but it might be the simplest way to get the point across. Thoughts?

Comment: I agree with everything you said. Might not be the best solution efficiency wise, but for the sake of teaching, creating a helper class that does the key updates would work well.